# When I import a CSV to MySQL Workbench two extra columns appears

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a CSV file with 9 columns but when I import it via MySQL Workbench it appears two extra columns with no values. A kind of solution is  to deselect them but I want an explanation and a permanent solution to avoid this. Why is this happening? I attach a screenshot to see exactly what I say.

[image]

Comment: I get this when there are additional delimiters at the tail end of the line. Look at the raw csv and check if there aren't some additional commas, tabs, spaces or whatever your delimiter is at the end of each line.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes in excel file type something and delete, excel file include or read blank columns or row.

If you delete those two columns after gameid in CSV file, after that import CSV file in mysql.